# How to Reload the activity/class in Android once i click the back button?

Tags: android, android-intent

i am in activityA from where i send data to activityB through intent, which gets stored in an arraylist in activityB, how make the arraylist of activityB empty once i click on back button ???
thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your ActivityB

```
      @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
            arraylistName.clear();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

this will override the back key press in ActivityB